How to stop clang-tidy running on sources from FetchContent?
I have this CMakeLists.txt:
# ...

find_program(CLANG_TIDY_EXE NAMES "clang-tidy")
set(CLANG_TIDY_COMMAND "${CLANG_TIDY_EXE}")

macro(target_enable_clang_tidy TARGET)
    set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES C_CLANG_TIDY "${CLANG_TIDY_COMMAND}")
    set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES CXX_CLANG_TIDY "${CLANG_TIDY_COMMAND}")
endmacro()

FetchContent_Declare(
        cxxopts
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts.git
        GIT_TAG 3bf268481da8208d171d8908e6491459de3651d7 #v3.2.0
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cxxopts)
message(cxxopts="${cxxopts_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/**/*.cpp"
)
message(SRC_FILES=${SRC_FILES})

add_library(filc_lib ${SRC_FILES})

target_include_directories(filc_lib PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" "${cxxopts_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

target_compile_options(filc_lib PUBLIC -Wall)

target_enable_clang_tidy(filc_lib)

# ...

When compiling the library, I get some errors coming from cxxopts.hpp (the sources downloaded by FetchContent). I found many posts about this problem but none with a clear (and working) response. So I try here.
The error I get (the same in each file linked to the dependency)
/home/kevin/dev/FIL/filc/build_release/_deps/cxxopts-src/include/cxxopts.hpp:30:10: error: 'cstdlib' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
   30 | #include <cstdlib>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~

Which is not really fatal as if I compile without clang-tidy it works well
Is there a way to tell clang-tidy to run on my sources but not on FetchContent sources?
I tried using set_source_files_properties(${DEP_FILES} PROPERTIES SKIP_LINTING ON) with DEP_FILES a glob_recurse on _deps directory. And also various answers from https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-to-prevent-clang-tidy-to-check-sources-added-with-fetchcontents/2871/1
If I remove all code about cxxopts, my tests got a similar error on googletest:
/home/kevin/dev/FIL/filc/build_unit_tests/_deps/googletest-src/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:52:10: error: 'cstddef' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
   52 | #include <cstddef>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~

And another test got that:
/home/kevin/dev/FIL/filc/tests/e2e/test_tools.h:27:10: error: 'string' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
   27 | #include <string>
      |          ^~~~~~~~

Can it be related to not finding the standard library?
